# Is this ostrichwood?

Tags: wood

The lady at the lumber dealer said this was ostrichwood. Is she pulling my leg?
[image: Ostrich wood plank]

Comment: I'm afraid that species has gone the way of the Dodo. I wouldn't want to egg you on, but I can't help EMUlating your approach.

Comment: I'd like to oPINE on this topic, but the conversation wood splinter off.

Comment: This conversation has lumbered off in the wrong direction. It's a knotty problem, that's for sure.

Comment: Given the size of the 2x4 and the nature of the question, should Greg be ostrich-sized?

Comment: Nah, he's a good egg, even if he comes across a bit cheep. We birds of a feather need to stick together.

Answer (score 3):

Wood ID questions are off-topic, but in this case we seem to have made an exception. I think it is clear from your very good picture that this is *not* ostrichwood.

You don't say where you are in the world, but given the grain structure this looks like emuwood.

Provide a picture of the end-grain so we can be sure, or just take a look at a quarter-sawn end: ostrichwood has two "toes" running down the grain, whereas emuwood has three.

Comment: Wouldn't emuwood be facing the other way?

Comment: Oh, I might have really laid an egg that time. Oh well. We'll see if the nest of the community downvotes this answer because I'm such a bird-brain.